# Finding General Solution by Integrating Factor Method for a Diff E.Q.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the General Solution $y'-2y = t^2e^{2t}$

I am stuck after finding $y = e^2t ∫e^{-2t}t^2e^{2t} dt$

Perhaps this isn't even right, but i believe I go forward with substitution.

Comment: You can cancel the exponentials in the integral, they are reciprocals

Comment: That's what I didn't catch! Thank you so much

Comment: Yep that's what the below answer shows too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{d}{dt}(e^{-2t}y)=e^{-2t}(y'-2y)=t^2$ and so $e^{-2t}y(t)=\frac13 t^3+c$